# Get Encoding of a DBF File

Tags: excel, character-encoding, dbf

I want to write a java programm that reads a DBF file which contains german letters like 'ö'. The problem I am facing is that I don't know which encoding the file uses. When I open notepad++ or the Windows editor, it says ANSI. But both programms show the 'ö' as '”'. But when I open Excel the 'ö' is shown.

I also tryed to change the encoding in notepad++, but nothing worked. Does someone know a way to see which encoding Excel is currently using/which encoding the file uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in your `.DBF` file are encoded as `cp850` (although any of `['cp1026', 'cp437', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp861', 'cp865', 'cp895']` could apply and hard to guess from given isolated example).

**Explanation**:

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
'ö'.encode('cp850').decode('cp1252')
```

> ```
> '”'
> ```

BTW, opening a `.dbf` file in a text editor gives no sense because it's a *binary* one (see [`.dbf` header structure](https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm)). Hence, any algorithm guessing *text* encoding (like `Notepad++`'s one) must fail…

Further reading (`DBase`/`FoxPro` never escaped from limitations of 8-bit encoding):

- [.dbf in WikipediA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.dbf) (mainly on history)
- [DBF File Encoding](https://dbf-software.com/dbf-file-encoding)